# How to loop through a file in bash starting at a custom line?

Tags: bash, file, loops

I have a file for which I want to loop through just a specific part of using a bash script. Here is an example of it's format:

```
FILE 1

(exclude)
. 

(Start loop from here)
.
.
.
(stop)
```

How do I loop through the file starting at the line I need and stop where required ? I assume I will need a for loop for this situation ? I do know the pattern for the first line if grep is required. Or the line number which is probably constant for all of my files (say starts at 5, stops at 9)

Comment: How is the part to parse described? is it after a specific pattern? from a line number?

Comment: Loop through to do what?  Please describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf the file has text which could serve as a pattern, but now that I think about it, the pattern on each line is different. So perhaps going by line numbers might be better.

Comment: Open and loop through the file, increment a counter on each iteration then you can use the counter to determine the line number and where to start doing something and where to finish

Comment: @Gary_W loop through to extract the first and fifth word in every line , append them to a new file (just the chosen lines).

Comment: We can play 20 Qs with you, or you can edit your Q to include sample input (with recs that should be processed and those that should be skipped), the required output from that input, your current code, output and error messages. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on selected text to have proper formatting for `code, data, ouput, error_msgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a state machine using AWK that toggles processing of the lines ON when the start pattern is found and either

1. toggles processing OFF when the stop pattern is found (this allows processing more than one start/stop group

or

2. exits the script when the stop pattern is found (this terminates all processing and speeds things up when you don't care about anything after the stop pattern)

```
awk '/stop/  {process = 0}
     process {print $1, $5}
     /start/ {process = 1}' inputfile
```

This could be put on one line, but I've broken it apart here for easier reading.

`process` is being used as a boolean variable. If it's true, print a couple of fields from the current line.

`/start/` and `/stop/` represent regular expressions to match strings that you will use to delimit the section(s) of the file you wish to process. You could instead use line numbers, for example you could change the `/start/` test to `NR == 120` to begin processing on the 120th line.

If you want the beginning and ending lines to be included in the processing, just move the `process` line after the `/start/` line and the `/stop/` line to be the last (essentially, reverse their order).

As I've shown it, this script will process multiple start/stop blocks within the file. If you want to only process the first (or only) you can change the `/stop/` line to:

```
/stop/  {exit)
```

Comment: Sound advice, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that you have the line numbers, you can use `tail`. For instance, to loop through the file starting at line 42, you could do a

```
tail -n +42 YOUR_FILE | while line
do
    process_line "$line"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: extract user name and home directory from `/etc/passwd` starting at `mail` and ending at `nobody`.

```
cat /etc/passwd |
sed -n '/^mail/,/^nobody/p' |
while IFS=: read user pw uid gid geco home sh line; do
  echo "$user: $home"
done
```